# Change variable value in parent from child javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to change variable value of parent window from child window

I am doing this way

**parent.html**

```
var check_var = false;
var myWindow = window.open("child.html", "", "width=auto, height=auto");
alert(check_var);// alerts false
```

**child.html**

```
window.opener.check_var=true=;
```

But its not working alerting `false` insted of true

Please see and suggest any way to do it

Thanks

Comment: you mean `window.opener.check_var===true;` is not alerting false?

Comment: @gurvinder372 no `check_var` in parent alerting false, I need to change `check_var` value to `true` from child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` *starts* the process of opening the window, but then your JavaScript code continues while the page is loaded. So your `alert` is happening before the child window is loaded and before the code in it modifies the variable.

Assuming `check_var` is a global, `opener.check_var` is indeed how you access that variable from `child.html`. It's just a timing thing.

You have several options for learning when the child has loaded:

1. Have the child use `postMessage` to send a message to the parent.
2. Have the child use `opener.someFunction()` to call a global function in the parent.
3. Use `myWindow.onload = function() { alert(check_var); };` to hook the `load` event on the child window, and then alert the value. Provided the code in `child.html` is in a `script` block and not waiting for some event, it will run before the `load` event fires.

Here's a complete working example:

`parent.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Parent</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Click to Open Child">
<script>
var check_var = false;
document.getElementById("the-button").onclick = function() {
    var wnd = window.open("child.html");
    wnd.onload = function() {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = "check_var = " + check_var;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    };
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`child.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Child</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var p = document.createElement('p');
if (opener) {
    opener.check_var = true;
    p.innerHTML = "Set check_var";
} else {
    p.innerHTML = "No opener";
}
document.body.appendChild(p);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did like `myWindow.onload = function() { alert(check_var); };` in parent and `opener.check_var=true` in child it still alerts `false`

Comment: @TallboY: There must be some small mistake in your code, it definitely works. I've posted a complete working example.

Comment: there is one small issue if you can help, it stoped working with jquery in `$(function(){ your code here })`

Comment: @TallboY: If your `var check_val` is *inside* that function, it's not a global anymore, and the child can't access it. You can move it outside the function so it's global again, and/or look into using `postMessage` (which is much more flexible and doesn't require globals; not using globals is a Good Thing™).

Comment: ok got it, thanks so much, if its not much to ask one more thing I am having trouble with, your code works with onload event, what if onload failed due to popup blocker how can I check that

Comment: @TallboY: I don't think you can other than, say, a timeout (e.g., `var timer = setTimeout(function() { /*...code to give up here..*/ }, 10000); and then `clearTimeout(timer)` in the `onload` callback). But if you call `window.open` in **direct** response to a user event (like a click), it's not likely to get blocked by a popup blocker. (If you don't, it is.)